# SharedElements transitions works on Go but don't on Back

Tags: android, transition, shared-element-transition

im learning how to use the sharedelements animations with navigation component.

The thing works when I call the new fragment , animating the objects but doesn't work when I push back.

my code es from the recycler view

```
    CardView cardviewBackgroundImage = view.findViewById(R.id.card_main_image);
    TextView storeName = view.findViewById(R.id.store_name);

    Map<View, String> transitionObjects = new HashMap<View, String>();
    transitionObjects.put(cardviewBackgroundImage, cardviewBackgroundImage.getTransitionName());
    transitionObjects.put(storeName, storeName.getTransitionName());

    FragmentNavigator.Extras extras = new FragmentNavigator.Extras.Builder()
            .addSharedElements(transitionObjects)
            .build();

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("subfix", subfix);
    bundle.putString("key", key);
    Navigation.findNavController(getView()).navigate(R.id.action_mainScreenFragment_to_placeViewFragment, bundle, null, extras);
```

and in de destination fragment my code is:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    postponeEnterTransition();
    sharedElementEnterTransition = TransitionInflater.from(getContext()).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.move);
    this.setSharedElementEnterTransition(sharedElementEnterTransition);


}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    String subfix = getArguments().getString("subfix");
    String key = getArguments().getString("key");

    CardView cardviewBackgroundImage = view.findViewById(R.id.card_main_image);
    TextView storeName = view.findViewById(R.id.store_name);
    cardviewBackgroundImage.setTransitionName("cardimage" + subfix + key);
    storeName.setTransitionName("storename" + subfix + key);
    startPostponedEnterTransition();
}
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you include your starting destination as well? You need to postpone that as well as per [this blog post](https://chris.banes.dev/2018/02/18/fragmented-transitions/)

Comment: sorry my English: what do you mean? the code in the view holder where I assingn the transition name?

Comment: See the blog post - you need to call `postponeEnterTransition()` in **first** fragment, not just second fragment.